# Azure guest account unable to log in

Tags: azure-activedirectory

We are using O365 and SharePoint online, and have many guest accounts, both with personal accounts and users on another O365 tenant. I have one particular user on an O365 tenant that when he accepts his invitation it errors out, error below.

**Status**  Failure

**Sign-in error code**  53004

**Failure reason**
User needs to complete Multi-factor authentication registration process before accessing this content. User should register for multi-factor authentication.

**Client app**  Browser

I have had their admin enable MFA on their tenant but still receiving same error. Any help in troubleshooting would be welcome!